# How to filter and split a string and put the results in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string variable with for example 2 items. These 2 items are seperated by a semicolon. I would like to get one of these items the parameter "currentWebTemplateName". After this I would like to split this item with by comma and set it in a key value dictionary. Code below works, but I think it could be better. Can someone tell me if there is some better solution?

```
private void GetWebTemplateSettings(string currentWebTemplateName)
{
    string allWebTemplateSettings = "template:SPSPERS#2,pageUrl:Social/Sites.aspx,webPartZone:LeftZone,title:Site Lidmaatschap;template:SITEDEFINITIONTEAM#0,pageUrl:Pages/Default.aspx,webPartZone:LeftZone,title:Site Lidmaatschap";
    string[] splittedWebTemplateSettings = allWebTemplateSettings.Split(';');
    foreach (string webTemplateSetting in splittedWebTemplateSettings)
    {
        if (webTemplateSetting.StartsWith(string.Format("template:{0}", currentWebTemplateName)))
        {
            provisioningSettings = webTemplateSetting.Split(',')
                              .Select(s => s.Split(':'))
                              .ToDictionary(a => a[0].Trim(), a => a[1].Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "better"? Less buggy? Shorter? Faster?

Comment: This question would be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CarstenKönig There are two levels of splitting here, and he correctly splits first on ';' and then on ','. And this is nowhere near valid JSON.

Comment: @Rawling "almost look" ....